# Setting up Coverage Exclusion in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, automated-tests

I want to set up coverage exlusion so that my test code is not reported as untested in my project overview.

I am working with SonarQube Version 7.0 (build 36138) and Visual Studio 2015 Projects. The results are reported from a runner that runs on jenkins.

I set up General Code Coverage rules on the SonarQube server using.
`Administration` -> `Configuration` -> `General Settings` -> `Analysis Scope` -> `Code Coverage` -> `Code Exclusions` where I set the rule to `**/_Test*/**/*.*`

The tool tip reads this would be the key `sonar.coverage.exclusions` which is what you are supposed to use according to [Narrowing The Focus](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus).

My expectation would be that the pattern I use matches.
`**` zero or more directories, followed by directory starting with `_Test*`, followed by `**` zero or more directories and finally matching all files `*.*`

However even when I rerun the project this rule is not applied.

The File

```
MySolution/_TestQ1/Component/MyComponentTest.cs
```

still makes it into the report.

Is there a way how I can quickly test my rule?
Is there something fundamentally wring with my rule?
How can I exclude the tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using 6.7 version, but I believe this will work with 7.0 version as well.

Basically if you go to Administration > Configuration > General Settings > Scanner for MSBuild you will see Test project pattern like:

```
[^\\]*test[^\\]*$
```

with information:

> DEPRECATED - Use 'sonar.msbuild.testProjectPattern' key in the Scanner
>   for MSBuild (client side) instead. Regular expression matched by test
>   project files path (.NET syntax)
>
> Key:
>   sonar.cs.msbuild.testProjectPattern

Those are places where you should add/modify your test projects pattern.

Comment: Ah, thanks - I did not realise msbuild runner would behave differently. I will just stick to the msbuild runners conventions. https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Miscellaneous+Advanced+Usages